# How do I take information in javascript and pass it to a java file and back?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I have about 2 different java files and one client file. I want to pass data into the java client file and collect the output using javascript.

For context, my project looks like this. I have a Linear Systems of Equations program. The client file has a method that takes input in the form of a string and filters it for the x coefficient, y coefficient, and result. 
The second file is a class LinearEquation with fields x coefficient, y coefficient, result, and slope. It has a method that takes another instance of LinearEquation and finds the intersection between both lines (returns the x and y values in an array of length two). If there is no result or infinite results the program returns two values of null.
I want to make a website that takes user input using javascript, and then that information is passed into the java files. 
How can I do this? Is there any software that can help me accomplish this?  I'm a beginner at programming so any pointers/tips/tricks you guys have is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your Java would need to be running server side, either as a application server (Tomcat, Websphere etc) where Java runs the entire back end, or you need some other langauge to run the back end that can make `shell_exec()` type calls to your java program.  Either way, client side (via Javascript) can communicate with back end by doing HTTP based calls much like a REST API would do.